# what is kerning and tracking of header 1 in header

Tags: html, css

I can't understand the what its mean and how to deal with it.

"kerning and tracking of Header 1 in header. Header 1 have id main to 5 and 10 respectively."

Comment: I do — not — know where you get this message. But `kerning` is the distance of two characters in `Typography`. Tracking is the distance of each character in a whole group.

Comment: where are you seeing this message?